bash function to execute arbitrary commands on multiple servers
I have a need to execute a command on a list of servers. For example, I want to search application restarts in the logs of an application on all load-balanced application servers:
cd /var/logs/rest-cli-io/
xcmd grep restart '*log'

Where xcmd the bash function is that executes the grep command on multiple servers.
Here is the xcmd bash function I came up with:
xcmd() {
  if [ "$1" == "" ]; then
    echo "Usage:   Specify command to execute on all app servers"
    echo "Example: cd /var/log/rest-cli-io; xcmd egrep restart '*.log'"
  else
    #servers=(app-srv-01 app-srv-02 app-srv-03)
    servers=($(cat /projects/app-servers/app-servers.txt | grep -v '#' | tr '\r\n' '  '))
    host="$HOSTNAME"
    command="$1"
    args="${@:2}"
    dir="$PWD"
    for server in ${servers[@]}; do
      echo "==========> $server: $command $args <=========="
      if [[ $server == $host ]]; then
        $command $args
      else
        ssh $server "cd $dir; $command $args"
      fi
    done
  fi
}

I am wondering what other folks did to address this need.

Automatically run commands over SSH on many servers.  There are many tools that can do what you want, but the only one that I can recommend  from personal experience is Ansible.

I am wondering why this question was closed because of "seeking recommendations for software libraries, tutorials, tools, books, or other off-site resources." I am clearly not seeking any of that. My goal was to find a short bash code snippet that addresses a need. See my answer.

I find it kind of strange, that you want to see other solutions, but don't reveal your own solution. If I do it in a certain way, how can I know whether my way is different from yours? If you just want to know whether your solution can be improved, I suggest that you ask this at [codereview.se]. If you want to know what possibilities are best to implement this feature, this would indeed be seeking recommendation.

@user1934428: I am showing my own solution, see my answer. Do you expect me to duplicate my answer in the question section?

Also SO encourages to submit your own answer, which I did...

IMO, what you posted should not go into an answer, but into your question. If your question is "how can I implement the feature differently than I did", an answer would not be your own solution, but a different solution. However it makes for sure sense to present your own solution in your question.

Ok, I duplicated my answer in the question section. Hope this helps to reopen the question...

So, this post now got 4 downvotes, still puzzled why. My intent was to be helpful to the SO community, sharing what I learned so others can use it, and figuring out what other people did with a similar question. There is no incentive to help out further...

Here is the xcmd bash function I came up with, which I added to ~/.bashrc:
xcmd() {
  if [ "$1" == "" ]; then
    echo "Usage:   Specify command to execute on all app servers"
    echo "Example: cd /var/log/rest-cli-io; xcmd egrep restart '*.log'"
  else
    #servers=(app-srv-01 app-srv-02 app-srv-03)
    servers=($(cat /projects/app-servers/app-servers.txt | grep -v '#' | tr '\r\n' '  '))
    host="$HOSTNAME"
    command="$1"
    args="${@:2}"
    dir="$PWD"
    for server in ${servers[@]}; do
      echo "==========> $server: $command $args <=========="
      if [[ $server == $host ]]; then
        $command $args
      else
        ssh $server "cd $dir; $command $args"
      fi
    done
  fi
}

Explanation:

the servers list can be hard-coded in the function, or read from a file accessible from all servers
xcmd executes an arbitrary command with arguments on all servers in the servers list
the command is executed locally if you are on a machine in the servers list, else it is run via a remote ssh command execution
for remote ssh execution it is assumed that the remote server is configured for password-less login

Example: Find the latest app restarts of the rest-cli-io application:
$ cd /var/log/rest-cli-io
$ xcmd grep restart 'access*.log' | sort | tail
access__2024-08-11_00.log:- 2024-08-10-03-55: rest-file-io app restart, listening on port 8070
access__2024-08-12_00.log:- 2024-08-11-03-54: rest-file-io app restart, listening on port 8070
access__2024-08-14_00.log:- 2024-08-13-03-55: rest-file-io app restart, listening on port 8070
access__2024-08-20_00.log:- 2024-08-19-03-55: rest-file-io app restart, listening on port 8070
access__2024-08-20_00.log:- 2024-08-19-11-15: rest-file-io app restart, listening on port 8070
access__2024-08-21_00.log:- 2024-08-20-03-55: rest-file-io app restart, listening on port 8070
access__2024-08-21_00.log:- 2024-08-20-18-07: rest-file-io app restart, listening on port 8070
==========> app-srv-01: grep restart access*.log <==========
==========> app-srv-02: grep restart access*.log <==========
==========> app-srv-03: grep restart access*.log <==========

